# Shiro Logout page: "There is no session with id" - Shiro

Tags: shiro, omnifaces

I want to have a normal logout from my p:commandButton:

I have in my backend bean this function:

```
public void logout() {
            SecurityUtils.getSubject().logout();
            
            SavedRequest savedRequest = WebUtils.getAndClearSavedRequest(Faces.getRequest());

            if (savedRequest == null) {
                Faces.redirect("/common/login.jsf");
            } else {
                Faces.redirect(savedRequest.getRequestUrl());
            }
}
```

But I got this:

> Caused by: org.apache.shiro.session.UnknownSessionException: There is no session with id [b4a41562-0d9e-4fc9-9d9d-ef7724d8efad]

Any idea how I can solve that?
I´m using also Omnifaces library.

Any idea what is wrong?

I´m using:
Shiro 1.7.0 and Omnifaces 3.10.1

Answer (score 0):

Shiro's `Subject.logout()` essentially clears the session (`session.invalidate()`). If the session has already been cleared, you wouldn't be able to clear it again.

If you are using [Shiro's Logout Filter](https://shiro.apache.org/web.html#default-filters) you do NOT need to make an additional call to `logout()`.